# How to replace strings using group by clause in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the below table where I need to replace the string in the column'Formula' with the matching input 'VALUE' column based on the group 'Yearmonth'.

```
IDNUM  formula                      INPUTNAME      VALUE    YEARMONTH
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1      imports(398)+imports(399)    imports(398)    17.000  2003:1
2      imports(398)+imports(399)    imports(398)    56.000  2003:2
3      imports(398)+imports(399)    imports(399)    15.000  2003:1
4      imports(398)+imports(399)    imports(399)    126.000 2003:2
```

For ex: from the above table i need the output as

```
Idnum Formula        Yearmonth
 1.    17.00 +15.00  2003:1
 2.    56.00 +126.00 2003:2
```

I tried with the below query but couldn't achieve it. How can this be done ?

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(FORMULA, INPUTName, AttributeValue) AS realvalues, 
    yearmonth 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY yearmonth
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `FOR XML PATH` for concatenation:

```
SELECT
    IDNUM = MIN(IDNUM),
    FORMULA = 
        (SELECT STUFF(
            (SELECT ' +' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Value)
            FROM Table1
            WHERE YEARMONTH = t1.YEARMONTH
            FOR XML PATH(''))
        ,1, 2, '')),
    YEARMONTH
FROM Table1 t1
GROUP BY YEARMONTH
```

Comment: This works fine... thanks a lot....I jus have one question will this works for any type of strings in the table or only for this type??

Comment: it seems this querey works for strings having '+' in the formula.... Is there any way we can replace only the string names without considering the mathematical symbols ??

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this type of replacement requires recursion:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by yearmonth order by idnum) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by yearmonth) as cnt
      from table t
     ),
     cte as (
      select t.seqnum, t.yearmonth, t.cnt,
             replace(formula, inputname, value) as formula
      from t
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select cte.seqnum, cte.yearmonth, cte.cnt,
             replace(formula, t.inputername, t.value)
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.yearmonth = t.yearmonth and t.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
    )
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as id,
       formula
from cte
where seqnum = cnt;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... but I believe the querey needs some modifications.. which I'm bit struggling to get the output.....

Comment: Hi Gordon.... I tried the code execution but I'm getting onlu null values...Could you please help me  out to achieve this one

Comment: @JamesRodix . . . Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.yearmonth,
   formula=REPLACE( (SELECT value AS [data()]
       FROM table t2
      WHERE t2.YEARMONTH= t1.YEARMONTH
      ORDER BY value
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), ' ', '+')
  FROM table t1
  GROUP BY YEARMONTH ;
```

if u need column idnum try this

```
declare @t table (idnum int identity(1,1),formula varchar(100),Yearmonth date)
insert into @t
    SELECT t1.yearmonth,
   formula=REPLACE( (SELECT value AS [data()]
       FROM table t2
      WHERE t2.YEARMONTH= t1.YEARMONTH
      ORDER BY value
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), ' ', '+')
  FROM table t1
  GROUP BY YEARMONTH ;
```

Comment: Hi... thanks for the suggestion... Its all the same from Felix Pamittan suggestions... please the comments given by me for his suggestions.. Would that be possible ??